# MongoError: Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value ObjectId

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to remove an element from an array inside a document. The Anon collection has an array called `reviews`. It should contain a list of objectIds I'm trying to remove one.

```
var strId = "5848ad1432d019f0350de350"
// function makeObjectId(str){
//     return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(str);
// }
var ObjectId = require("mongoose").Types.ObjectId;
// var ObjectIdVersion = new ObjectId(strId);
// var ObjectIdVersion = makeObjectId(strId);

var query = {_id : strId};
var pull = {"$pull" : {reviews : new ObjectId(strId)}};
Review.findOne(query)
    .then(function(doc){
        console.log("reviewDoc", doc)
        // Anon.findOneAndUpdate({reviews : new ObjectId(strId)}, pull, {new : true})
        //     .then(function(doc){
        //         console.log(doc)
        //     })
        //     .catch(function(err){
        //         console.log(err)
        //     });
        Anon.update({reviews : new ObjectId(strId)},
                    {$pull : {reviews : new ObjectId(strId) }},
                    {new : true}
                )
        .then(function(doc){
            console.log("ANON :: ", doc)
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err)
        })
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
```

When I do `Anon.find()` without the $pull part and the `new :true` part I do get the Anons document with the id in the array. So I thinking finding the document is not the problem. For some reason I can't use pull. I thought it would work.

EDIT:

from the find:

```
[ { _id: 57ca6df982d3a41814a18213,
    __v: 1,
    pointsRecord: [],
    userType: 'anon',
    transfered: { isTransfer: false },
    images: [],
    defaultImage: 'defaultPreppy.png',
    createdOn: Wed Dec 07 2016 20:38:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    repPoints: 0,
    usefulness: [],
    shortId: 'r1WYY4IQl',
    reviews: [ 5848ad1432d019f0350de350 ] },
  { _id: 5848ace932d019f0350de34c,
    momented: 'Dec 7, 2016',
    __v: 3,
    pointsRecord: [ [Object] ],
    userType: 'anon',
    transfered: { isTransfer: false },
    images:
     [ 'shipyourreptiles.com-SJbl67IXl-0',
       'stashtea.com-SJbl67IXl-0' ],
    defaultImage: 'defaultPreppy.png',
    createdOn: Wed Dec 07 2016 19:44:25 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    repPoints: 3,
    usefulness: [],
    shortId: 'SJbl67IXl',
    reviews: [ 5848ad1432d019f0350de350 ] } ]
```

EDIT:: Part of my schema that shows reviews:

```
var anonSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    reviews : [{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Review"}], 
    updatedtString : {type : String},
    shortId : {type : String, unique : true, default : shortId.generate},
```

Comment: Can you include the Anons document you get back with find?

Comment: I did in the edit

Comment: Thanks, nothing obvious there.  What's the schema look like for `reviews`?

Comment: I showed the reviews schema